# Advise on panic error writing buffer to io.Writer

Tags: go

I'm having some issue with writing `[]float32` data in stream order to a `io.Writer` buffer in Go.

I have the following 16 bit per pixel image [noise16.jpeg](https://github.com/observerly/iris/blob/main/images/noise16.jpeg) that I open, and read as follows in my test:

```golang
func TestNewFITSImageFrom2DDataWriteFloatData(t *testing.T) {
    f, err := os.Open("../../images/noise16.jpeg")

    if err != nil {
        t.Errorf("Error opening image: %s", err)
    }

    defer f.Close()

    img, err := jpeg.Decode(f)

    if err != nil {
        t.Errorf("Error decoding image: %s", err)
    }

    bounds := img.Bounds()

    ex := make([][]uint32, bounds.Dx())

    for x := 0; x < bounds.Dx(); x++ {
        col := make([]uint32, bounds.Dy())
        ex[x] = col
    }

    for j := 0; j < bounds.Dy(); j++ {
        for i := 0; i < bounds.Dx(); i++ {
            r, g, b, _ := img.At(i, j).RGBA()
            lum := 0.299*float64(r) + 0.587*float64(g) + 0.114*float64(b)
            ex[i][j] = uint32(lum)
        }
    }

    var fit = NewFITSImageFrom2DData(ex, 16, 2, int32(bounds.Dx()), int32(bounds.Dy()))

    var w io.Writer

    err = writeFloat32Array(w, fit.Data, true)

    if err != nil {
        t.Errorf("Error writing float32 array: %s", err)
    }
}
```

I essentially open the image, and read in each pixel to an "exposure" array (the `[]float32` data). I then pass the data to the following method, with an instantiated writer:

```golang
// Writes FITS binary body data in network byte order.
// Optionally replaces NaNs with zeros for compatibility with other software
func writeFloat32Array(w io.Writer, data []float32, replaceNaNs bool) error {
    bufLen := 16 * 1024

    buff := make([]byte, bufLen)

    // Process the data in chunks of BUFFER_LENGTH bytes:
    for block := 0; block < len(data); block += (bufLen >> 2) {

        size := len(data) - block

        if size > (bufLen >> 2) {
            size = (bufLen >> 2)
        }

        for offset := 0; offset < size; offset++ {
            d := data[block+offset]

            if replaceNaNs && math.IsNaN(float64(d)) {
                d = 0
            }

            val := math.Float32bits(d)

            buff[(offset<<2)+0] = byte(val >> 24)
            buff[(offset<<2)+1] = byte(val >> 16)
            buff[(offset<<2)+2] = byte(val >> 8)
            buff[(offset<<2)+3] = byte(val)
        }

        _, err := w.Write(buff[:(size << 2)])

        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }

    // Complete the last partial block, for strictly FITS compliant software
    bytesWritten := len(data) << 2

    lastPartialBlock := bytesWritten % 2880

    if lastPartialBlock != 0 {
        sb := strings.Builder{}

        for i := lastPartialBlock; i < 2880; i++ {
            sb.WriteRune(' ')
        }

        _, err := w.Write([]byte(sb.String()))

        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return err
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

My testing is coming back with a Panic error:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference [recovered]
    panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x18 pc=0x119101f]
```

Which signifies that this line is throwing an error from inside the `writeFloat32Array` function in the first iteration of the `for block := 0; block < len(data); block += (bufLen >> 2)` loop:

```golang
_, err := w.Write(buff[:(size << 2)])
```

Could anyone shed some light on what I have possibly done wrong? My instincts are telling me something around `bufLen` is incorrect, this should probably be the number of bytes in the image, rather than `16384` bytes?

However, when I set a very large number ... I still see the same error?

I have also tried as @jdizzle suggested, and encoded with the binary package but I am still seeing the panic error:

```
// Writes FITS binary body data in network byte order.
// Optionally replaces NaNs with zeros for compatibility with other software
func writeFloat32Array(w io.Writer, data []float32, replaceNaNs bool) error {
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)

    err := binary.Write(buf, binary.BigEndian, data)

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    _, err = w.Write(buf.Bytes())

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to using the encoding/binary package? First glance suggested there’s buffer boundary edge conditions that aren’t being met in the serialization code. This should be solvable using stdlib without needing to implement it yourself.

Comment: @jdizzle So just encode `data []float32` and then write that output?

Comment: Correct; you can binary.Write it straight to whatever writer you’re using.

Comment: @jdizzle Ok cool. Could you provide me an example of what you would do, for reference. I can't seem to reference in the docs how to write anything to bytes. As well, I need to ensure that the total bytes written are `% 2880` === 0, so I have the method that adds with some extra bytes ...

Comment: Okay, seeing how I would convert that revealed a bigger problem. You pass an uninitialized (null) io.Writer to your serialization function. That would certainly  cause a null pointer deference.

Comment: @jdizzle I've updated my question with how I think it should be implemented, but I am still seeing a panic error when I write the bytes buffer? What am I doing wrong :(

Comment: @jdizzle Ahhhhhhh, so what is the usage for the io.Writer?

Comment: @jdizzle Perhaps something like: `var w io.Writer = os.Stdout`

Comment: Exactly; io.Writer is an interface pointer. You have to have an implementation somewhere for it to work.

Comment: @jdizzle Thank you, appreciate the advise on this. I assumed the buffer was the implementation but it needs some sort of output e.g., stout or file output. Appreciate the pro-tip! :)